# How to copy a created file to the network drive in Python?

Tags: python, shutil

I have a csv file that I created with an API call. I download a report and then write it to the csv. The last part of this project is to move the created file to the network drive but I'm running into trouble. My code is as follows:

```
def generate_report(id):
    report_api = rapid7vmconsole.ReportApi(client)
    response = report_api.get_report(id)
    response_string = str(response)
    print(response_string)
    dumped_json = json.dumps(response_string)
    print(dumped_json)
    reloaded = json.loads(dumped_json)
    print(type(reloaded))
    y = ast.literal_eval(reloaded)
    for key, value in y.items():
        print(key, value)
    name = (y["name"])
    print(name)
    response_container = []
    response_container.append(response)
    current_date = datetime.now()
    date_string = current_date.strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S")

    if response in response_container:
        print('logged')
        #print(response)
        report_download = report_api.download_report(3701, 'latest')
        with open(name + '_' + date_string + '.csv', 'w') as f:
            f.write(report_download)
            shutil.copy(f, dest_temp)
generate_report(3701)
```

Where I'm running into trouble is the shutil.copy. I run into a type error. Says path should be in string, bytes os.PathLike or integer. no _io.TextWrapper. dest_temp is the network drive location. Do I have to close the file first or something? Any help is appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Can you write the error here as it is?

Comment: TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not _io.TextIOWrapper